# IntelliJ - Sources not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I implement a method in a class and I implement all methods to override I get things like:

`@Override
    public void setMinAndMaxCornerValues(int i, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7, int i8)`

Those argument names aren't really helping. I am expecting: `int minXIndex, int minX, int minYIndex, int minY, int maxXIndex, int maxX, int maxYIndex, int maxY)`.

If I select the not so helpfull one and do **go to > super method** then I see the following (allong with all the methods with 'missing' argument names):

[image]

When I click **Attach Sources...** It goes to the jar file. But selecting it and pressing **ok** doesn't change a thing.

How can this problem be solved?

In case it matters, I created that jar file.
.

Comment: Is this an opensource library that you are extending ?

Comment: You get `i`, `i1`, `i2` etc. because IntelliJ doesn't know the sensible names, because it doesn't have access to the source code for the method you're overriding. In "Attach Sources" you shouldn't point it to the jar file itself, but to the directory containing the source code for the jar.

Comment: @sam, it's a library I created that i'm extending in another library. And yes it's open source.

Comment: can your intellij do updates ? it might simply be a problem of connection for intellij.

Comment: @Jesper, it asks for a jar/zip or directory so I wonder why it doesn't work with the jar. I choose the directory now but now I can edit the code from a project in another project which is a bit scary. Also it should be possible with just a jar, I have from other libraries also a jar imported and there it goes ok.

Comment: You can point it to a directory or to a jar or zip file that contains the sources - note that that is not the same as the jar file that contains the compiled classes.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper, that helped.  I pointed it to the actual source instead of just the jar of compiled classes and it works.